# Script for download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download

### How to write a script to download all videos from the links in a webpage

Hey Guys,
I want to write a script to download all rails screen casts from this location http://railscasts.com/episodes/archive 
Any ideas on how this can be automated?

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go with `wget -l inf -r -np http://railscasts.com/episodes`.